# Verificar si un correo electrónico existe en un registro de usuarios con PHP

Tags: php, email

Como puedo verificar si un correo electrónico existe en un registro de usuarios sin tener que mandar un mensaje de activación al correo proporcionado? Sé que existe la funcion de filter_sanitize_email, pero quiero saber si realmente el correo que proporcionan existe. Gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

desgraciadamente no hay forma de saber si un correo electrónico existe si no es enviando un email a esa dirección y verificar la respuesta del servidor de correo. la función filter_sanitize_email simplemente verificará si el formato de la dirección es correcto (algo@dominio.algo), pero no pasará de ahí.
Afortunadamente, existen APIS gratuitas que hacen ese trabajo por ti, te dejo un enlace donde puedes encontrar más información al respecto.
https://geekflare.com/es/email-verification-api/
Un saludo, espero haber sido de ayuda.